# poi: sheet.autoSizeColumn needs .ttf files

Tags: apache-poi, solaris, truetype

call to autoSizeColumn hangs

according to this URL
http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/HSSFSheet-autoSizeColumn-method-doesn-t-work-properly-on-Linux-system-td4270552.html

I need .ttf files that are not included in JDK or JRE distribution under solaris.

It seems working under windows

the problem is i have been looking for these files for 4 hours without success

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? Why POI needs them? How to install them on Solaris? How to pinch the files off a nearby Windows box and give them to Solaris? Something else?

Comment: my problem is that autoSizeColumn is not working. web server hangs when i use this method.


According to the link i posted, java needs graphical environment (font files) to be able to calculate characters width. these files must be in /java/jre/lib/fonts directory. I cannot find them

Comment: Did you try locating them on a box where your code does work, then simply copy them over and check that Solaris sees them?

Comment: You said it worked on Windows? That Windows box will have them on it. Otherwise, try google - I found plenty of hits on the first page which covered how to download them and extract them!

Answer (score 0):

If it generates .xlsx the default font is Calibri which font is from Microsoft "ClearType" font package and your Linux probably do not have it. Install it or use a font provided in system running the softwate.

See more about fonts on:
https://www.pcworld.com/article/2863497/how-to-install-microsoft-fonts-in-linux-office-suites.html